# How do I query by column name on my Sprints page's Taskboard in Azure Boards?

Tags: azure-devops

Please tell me that I am missing something.  It looks like I can query by Kanban column names on the Boards page boards, but I can't query Sprint page's Taskboards column names.

Does the **Board Column** query field not apply to the Sprint page's Taskboards columns?
If not, is there another query field that does?